# How to do BULK INSERT into PostgreSQL without specifying physical csv file in Apache NiFi

Tags: postgresql, csv, apache-nifi, bulkinsert

I need to do BULK INSERT into PostgreSQL table in Apache NiFi without specifying the physical csv file in COPY command. I just cannot store the CSV files on the disk and would like to do BULK INSERT using a flow file that is coming from previous processors and is already in CSV format (or I can change it to json, that's not an issue).

Please advise, what is the best way to do this in Apache NiFi?

Comment: did you try `PutSQL` processor?

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde I am trying to use PutSQL but I don't know how to specify not the physical csv file but csv file that is coming from the previous processor.

This command doesn't work. Please advise what I should change here? I can see that attribute ${filename} is coming from the previous processor.

COPY position__c (Id, Name, Description__c)
FROM ${filename} DELIMITER ';';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL's `COPY` operation requires a path to a file. I'd recommend looking at PutDatabaseRecord which generates a PreparedStatement based on your CSV data and executes the statement in a single batch (unless `Maximum Batch Size` is set)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As far as I know, I have to specify the statement type for this processor (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) but there is no option for COPY command, am I right?

Actually I need something like this but it doesn't work. ${filename} is the attribute that is coming from the previous processor, the csv file is not stored on the disk, it's just going through NiFi queue.

COPY position__c (Id, Name, Description__c)
FROM ${filename} DELIMITER ';';

Comment: Oh, I think I get what you mean. So, PutDatabaseRecord is the same as bulk insert into the database? I need to regularly insert 8000-10000 records as fast as possible.

Comment: Refer this one - https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord/

Comment: You can also try ExecuteStreamCommand to execute `psql` or something (using COPY FROM STDIN), it will get the Flowfile contents as STDIN https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-copy.html